# Concurrent Access Sparse Matrix in Java

Tags: java, concurrency, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

I'm looking for a matrix / linear algebra library in Java that provides a sparse matrix that can be written to concurrently from different threads.  Most of the libraries I've come across either do not provide sparse matrices at all, or 1.) back them with an open addressed hash map, or 2.) store then in CSR or CSC format which is not at all amenable to multithreaded construction.  Right now I'm gather the entries in parallel using a concurrent hash map and them populating the sparse matrix from a single thread, but this seems like a waste of resources (space to store the concurrent hash map, and time to essentially fill in the matrix twice).

Comment: Have you tried Colt? http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/

Comment: I've looked at colt.  The problem with their sparse matrix (http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/api/cern/colt/matrix/impl/SparseDoubleMatrix2D.html), as detailed in the implementation note, is that it uses an OpenIntDoubleHashMap, and is therefore not synchronized.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just magically make sparse matrix algebra routines scalably parallel. Tackling these issues involves some of the most complex numerical analysis algorithms around and is still the subject of intense research.

You don't say what you want to do with these matrices but I imagine that you want solution to systems of linear equations. If you want that in parallel then you'll need a 3rd party library, very large matrices, and likely some money.

The most common way to assemble sparse matrices is to assemble them in triplet format and convert to compressed row or column format. The assembly can be expensive but it is easy to do in parallel. Just let each thread have its own list of triplets and splice them together before converting to compressed format.

Comment: Hey David, thanks for your response.  I actually don't want to solve a linear system with the matrix.  I do, however, need to compute a matrix vector product.  I gather from your response, however, that building a sparse matrix concurrently is more of a "roll your own" type thing?

Comment: matrix vector product can run in parallel but you need big matrices to make it worthwhile. Of course you don't need compressed storage for that operation but it might still be more efficient. How do you currently build you matrices? Do you use triplets?

Comment: Right now I'm using the Apache Commons Math sparse matrix implementation.  Its one of the ones I was referring to above that is not thread-safe, and is backed by a hash map.  I currently build the matrix by placing all of the entries into a ConcurrentHashMap, and then build the Matrix from this hash map sequentially in a single thread.  I guess I need a matrix class to which I can just hand off an already constructed triplet list, or which is inherently thread-safe.

Comment: They range from small (~10,000 x 10,000) to medium (~100,000 x 100,000) in size -- some may be larger in the future.  They tend to be around 1% dense.

Comment: If you are just multiplying the matrix by something, you don't need it to be thread safe.  You can split your problem in parallel tasks and just be careful when you put the results from the tasks together.  You also have to be careful that all tasks start with the exact same matrix.

Comment: The problem I'm having is mostly in performing a parallel construction of the matrix.  While the matrix is largely sparse, I actually have to compute a value for most entries (it just ends up being 0 or below my threshold).  The operation of computing values is inherently parallel, and the machine I'm running on has 32 cpus to burn.  However, the actual construction of the matrix is not thread-safe, and that's what I'm trying to work around currently.

Comment: Maybe you could just put your non-null results (ix, iy, non-null value) in some temporary thread-safe collection object and then just fill the values in a Colt sparse matrix?

Comment: Yea, that's exactly what I'm doing now actually. I'm throwing the results into a ConcurrentHashMap and then populating the matrix with them.  This works, but it's just a bit of a waste of both space and time.  Space b/c I'm storing the hash separately (the matrix requires its own storage) and time b/c I have to loop over the non-zero elements an extra time to insert them into the matrix.

Comment: @nomad @toto do you even need to form the matrix? Just do the multiplication as you are going along and remember the result rather than the matrix. That would allow you to do the full multiplication also.

Comment: but if you have to form the matrix then don't use thread safe containers. Let each thread have its own private container and so you don't need to pay for synchronisation.

Comment: I do need to form the matrix, because I need to do the multiplication repeatedly.  I've written a wrapper for netlib-java, and am using the Arpack interface to compute a few of the dominant eigenvectors of the matrix.  To achieve this, Arpack requires me to perform a number of iterations of a matrix vector product with a vector it supplies.  Since I'll be iterating the product (with the same matrix) I do think I need to build and store the matrix. @David do you know of a good matrix package where I can construct a sparse matrix by giving it a list of triplets?

Comment: Ok now you are giving us some useful information. Arpack is wonderful by the way! You don't need compressed storage, you can do it with triplets. And you don't need concurrent containers, just use a fork and join algorithm to build the matrix, each thread with private data.

Answer (score 0):

I remember the matrices in [parallel colt](http://sites.google.com/site/piotrwendykier/software/parallelcolt) being thread safe. The library is a multithreaded version of colt.

Comment: It seems that, though some of the operations matrix operations are parallelized in "parallel colt", the actual sparse matrix implementation is largely the same as that of colt.  This means it uses the same backend storage, which is not thread-safe to write.